# Select values only depending on comma based string to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

A1= 10,20,30,40,50,60,90,100,110

If I want to write 10,20,70 in cell B1 then it should deny me as 70 is not is cell A1. Ex-if I write irrespective of order in B1 cell 10,50,40,20 it allows me but as I type 10,50,80,30 it should restrict.
Please help me out.
[image: Find image here]

Comment: The keyword to look for is data validation: See [Apply data validation to cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249), give it a try. If you get stuck or errors come back with a concrete question and show what exactly you have tried • You might also benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: But Sir, It is a comma-separated value. How to apply data validation on comma based values.

Comment: Well this *"restrict only one time entry"* changes everything and you need to write VBA code for this. Use the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) to validate your entry and if it is not valid you can use the [Application.Undo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.undo). Give it a try yourself. Note that Stack overflow is not a code writing service therefore you need to show the code you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried **anything**? you've tagged the question with VBA, but posted nothing, Please, post what you've tried, what errors are you getting, don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please remove vba tag, this can be solved by function!

Answer (score 3):

Using formulas only, as long as the order is kept the same (initial 1-digit only solution and then 2-digit below):

[image]

Enter this formula into the data validation like this, as a custom formula:

Data > Data Validation:

[image]

The formula for B2 is:

`=IFERROR(MATCH("*" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","*")," ","*") & "*",A2,0),0)`

How this works is that it searches for the entry in the B cell in the A cell with `Match()` but we also add `"*"` to the start and the end so that we look up with wildcards (i.e. we find it anywhere in the string). Also, we replace any commas and any spaces with wildcards `"*"` so that the order is not important.

So in this case, when we enter `"2,3,8"` in cell B2, we do essentially this:

`MATCH("*2*3*8*", "1,2,3,7,8",0)`

and of course, this gives a positive match and so the validation is valid.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @Peh - this solution only works for 1-digit numbers.

If we want to extend that to 2-digit numbers then we need a bit more creativity.

I think I've come up with a solution but it requires a small change in the validation string in column A.

[image]

you need to enter your list like `"1,3,7,9,#12,14,22"`

Meaning between your last 1-digit number and your first 2-digit number you need to add a hashtag `"#"`.

Then the new formula works (this if for cell B4):

`=IFERROR(MATCH("*" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(REPLACE(B4,SEARCH(",??,",B4&","),1,",#,"),B4  & "#"),",","*")," ","*") & "*",A4,0),0)`

It works by searching for `",??,"` - i.e. the first 2-digit number in your entry, and replacing it with `",#,"` (note, I need to add a comma to the end of your entry in-case you only have a single 2-digit number).

Then we search for this with all the other replacing of commas and spaces for the Astrix wildcard `"*"`.

So if you enter `"1,3,12"` we essentially change that to `"*1*3*#*12*"`

This means that if you enter `"1,3,1"` it is no longer valid. Previously, with the first answer, I gave above, this would have matched as valid as the 1 from the 12 would have validated the final 1 we entered when considering the wildcards we used.

This solution is valid for all 2-digit numbers up to 99 I believe but it won't work after 100, unless we add an additional creative step like adding another character before 3-digit numbers and handling that similarly.

Comment: Nice non-VBA solution! But it only works correctly for one digit numbers. Test `1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12` and `1,3,2` will be considered valid because the last `2` validates againts the `2` in `12`.

Comment: That's a good point, I can't immediately think of a workaround for that. Perhaps the solution is limited to one-digit numbers. I'll have a quick think if there is any other wildcards I could use etc.

Comment: I have a way to handle 2-digit numbers as well now, as long as the OP is ok to modify the validation string a little to separate the 1-digit and 2-digit validation with a "#" like "1,3,7,9,#12,14,22" - then the new formula should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use worksheet events and dictionaries.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vS1, vS2, v1, v2
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim c As Object

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set c = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Target.Offset(0, -1)
        vS1 = Split(rng, ",")

        For Each v1 In vS1
            If Not dic.exists(v1) Then
                dic.Add v1, v1
            End If
        Next v1
        vS2 = Split(Target, ",")
        For Each v2 In vS2
            If Not c.exists(v2) Then
                c.Add v2, vS
            Else
                MsgBox "Please input correct Data!! "
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If Not dic.exists(v2) Then
                MsgBox "Please input correct Data!! "
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next v2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use `Target.CountLarge` ([Range.CountLarge property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge)). The `Count` property will generate an overflow error if the specified range has more than 2,147,483,647 cells. So the actual code throws an unhandled exception for example if you copy paste a full worksheet.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, You'r right. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I have taken (notice the bold paragraphs) then try it

1. Click Formula tab -> Name manager -> **add new formula name:**

> ```
> =IFERROR(FIND("," &TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!$D1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99*(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&(LEN(Sheet2!$D1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!$D1,",",""))+1)))-1)+1,99))&",", ","& Sheet2!$A1 &","),0)
> ```

2. Click Data tab -> data validation -> allow custom -> add formula -> add title error alert

> ```
> =AND(arr,FREQUENCY(arr,arr)<=1)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> =AND(AND(arr),AND(FREQUENCY(arr,arr)<=1))
> ```

Unfortunately, this seems to exceed the function length limit in datavalidation
and it also doesn't work with name lists so I'll **put this formula in cell G1**, now it will work

```
G1=AND(AND(arr),AND(FREQUENCY(arr,arr)<=1))
```

**3. And in the data validation set this formula:**

```
=INDIRECT("G1")
```

[image]

To explain how it works take a look at your request

- The numbers must be in the numbers you provide, the arr function will solve that
- The numbers cannot be dulicate, tested using the frequency(arr, arr)
  function.
- Finally combine these conditions with the [and] function